# Mac Shortcuts App boots scripts slowly with delay

Tags: macos, sirishortcuts

I create shortcuts in Shortcuts.app (macOS 12) to resizing/moving the current window by JavaScript.

The question is: there is a delay time (about 0.2~0.3 sec) after I press the keyboard shortcut to launch the scripts. It's quite annoying. How can I improve that?

I used [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/) with Lua scripts to do the same jobs, and it responds very quickly/instantly without any delay.

---

### Shortcuts implementation

Move current window to top left corner (using hotkey ⌘⇧⌥← & [you can download this shortcut here](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/ee12c6bee38c410f89b0800fa71be902)):

```js
function run(input, parameters) {
    var frontAppName = Application("System Events").processes.whose({frontmost: {'=': true}})[0].name();
    var frontApp = Application(frontAppName);
    var topWindow = frontApp.windows[0];
    var windowBounds = topWindow.bounds();
    windowBounds.x = 0;
    windowBounds.y = 0;
    topWindow.bounds = windowBounds;
}
```

Move current window to top right corner (using hotkey ⌘⇧⌥→ & [you can download this shortcut here](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/667493f0a02a4c9fb7a1ae0f530097ce)):

```js
function run(input, parameters) {
    var frontAppName = Application("System Events").processes.whose({frontmost: {'=': true}})[0].name();
    var frontApp = Application(frontAppName);
    var topWindow = frontApp.windows[0];
    var windowBounds = topWindow.bounds();
    var desktopBounds = Application("Finder").desktop.window().bounds();

    windowBounds.x = desktopBounds.width - windowBounds.width;
    windowBounds.y = 0;

    topWindow.bounds = windowBounds;
}
```